# When passing data from parent component to child component via props, the data appears to be undefined in the mounted hook of the child component

Tags: vue.js

In my parent component:

```
<UsersList :current-room="current_room" />
```

In the child component:

```
export default {
    props: {
        currentRoom: Object
    },
    data () {
        return {
            users: []
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.$nextTick( async () => {
            console.log(this.currentRoom) // this, weirdly, has the data I expect, and id is set to 1
            let url = `${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL}/chat_room/${this.currentRoom.id}/users`
            console.log(url) // the result: /api/chat_room/undefined/users
            let response = await this.axios.get(url)
            this.users = response.data
        })
    },
}
```

When I look at the page using vue-devtools, I can see the data appears:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this issue in the past – as have [many others](https://www.google.com/search?q=vue%20props%20not%20available%20in%20mounted). For whatever reason, you can't rely on props being available in the component's `mounted` handler. I think it has to do with the point at which `mounted()` is called within [Vue's lifecycle](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram).

I solved my problem by watching the prop and moving my logic from mounted to the watch handler. In your case, you could watch the `currentRoom` property, and make your api call in the handler:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    currentRoom: Object
  },
  data() {
    return {
      users: []
    }
  },
  watch: {
    currentRoom(room) {
      this.$nextTick(async() => {
        let url = `${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL}/chat_room/${room.id}/users`
        let response = await this.axios.get(url)
        this.users = response.data
      })
    }
  },
}
```

I don't think you really need to use `$nextTick()` here, but I left it as you had it. You could try taking that out to simplify the code.

By the way, the reason `console.log(this.currentRoom);` shows you the room ID is because when you pass an object to `console.log()`, it binds to that object until it is read. So even though the room ID is not available when `console.log()` is called, it becomes available before you see the result in the console.